# Retrieving data from SNMP probe variables

Tags: security, snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmpv2c

When SNMP walking or using a 'Single OID Viewer' probe I can retrieve any of the OIDs information. However, when trying to use the custom probe from the interactive snmp probe creator all of the OIDs return '[N/A]'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am adding more info below for context
  1. snippet code for a custom probe
  2. what I am expecting 
  3. What my code returns

1. Below is an example code for the OID variables I require

-- The purpose of the code is to record status data from a device and displays the device status for user.

```
<snmp-device-variables>
TLPPOIName_,     spvLDasName.${Slot},DEFAULT, "TLPPOIName"
PoiDescription_, spvLDasCommercialDescription.${Slot},DEFAULT, "PoiDescription"
PoiAttDl1_,      spvLDasAttDigDl.${Slot}.1,DEFAULT,         "Poi Attenuation Dl path 1"
PoiAttDl2_,      spvLDasAttDigDl.${Slot}.2,DEFAULT,         "Poi Attenuation Dl path 2"
PeakPwr1_,       spvLDasPeakPwrDl.${slot}.1, DEFAULT,       "PeakPwr path 1"
PeakPwr2_,       spvLDasPeakPwrDl.${slot}.2, DEFAULT,       "PeakPwr path 2"
PwrAlarm_,       spvLDasPwrAlarmHysteresis.${Slot},DEFAULT, "PwrAlarm"
</snmp-device-variables>`
```

```
<datasets>
     $PoiAttDl1_, "PoiAttDl1", "dB", "true", "Poi Attenuation Dl path 1"
     $PoiAttDl2_, "PoiAttDl2", "dB", "true", "Poi Attenuation Dl path 2"
     $PeakPwr1_,  "PeakPwr1", "dBm", "true", "PeakPwr path 1"
     $PeakPwr2_,  "PeakPwr2", "dBm", "true", "PeakPwr path 2"
     $PwrAlarm_,  "PwrAlarm", "dBm", "true", "PwrAlarm"  
</datasets>`
```

```
<snmp-device-display>
\B5\TLPPOI\P0\
\4\ TLPPOIName:\0\ $TLPPOIName_\M0\
\4\ PoiDescription:\0\$PoiDescription_ \M0\
\4\ Poi Attenuation Dl path 1:\0\$PoiAttDl1_ \M0\
\4\ Poi Attenuation Dl path 2:\0\$PoiAttDl2_ \M0\
\4\ PeakPwr path 1:\0\$PeakPwr1_ \M0\
\4\ PeakPwr path 2:\0\$PeakPwr2_ \M0\
\4\ PwrAlarm:\0\$PwrAlarm_\M0\
</snmp-device-display>
```

2. SNMP walk results: Below are example of values I expect to see
     VZW 800
      20
      2
3. Display window after I use the custom probe I wrote
   TLPPOIName: [N/A]

Comment: You need to give more context. If possible, show screen shots.

Comment: I have added more contexts, unfortunately I couldn't load images to my edits.